# Have MIT license text to be added if software is just using?

Tags: mit, license

Let's assume that I sell Angular course on Udemy. In this case, I wonder whether I have to add Angular's MIT license text to my course or not.

If I have to do this, is it enough to add the license link (https://angular.io/license) to course description on Udemy?

**EDIT:**

How I use the software:

- I tell how to install it, how to create an app, how to use Angular features, etc.
- I show the original text in https://angular.io and in sub-pages from web browser
- I don't change source code and the text in https://angular.io and in sub-pages
- I just use the ready system

Comment: Didn't you ask essentially this question yesterday? The answer is still "The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in all copies or substantial portions of the Software."

Comment: The license applies when you distribute the software or parts of it. Not when you talk about it or write about it

Comment: I am not sure because I use the software and the license text says ".. including without limitation the rights to **use**, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell copies of the Software .." before the next line of the text.

Answer (score 2):

As I read what you've written above, none of the course materials distributed to students contain MIT-licensed code, nor anything that would make them derivatives of the code in copyright terms.

Assuming this to be correct, then as I read it, you are not obliged to reproduce the licence statement and copyright lines.  The rights given to you, which include usage, are given on condition that you reproduce those texts when you reproduce verbatim copies, or substantial portions, of that software.  Since you are not reproducing copies or substantial portions of the software, the obligation has no effect in your case.

If you are reproducing enough of their documentation (eg, the content at https://angular.io/) to require a copyright licence, then as the above page says "*Documentation licensed under CC BY 4.0.*", so you will have CC BY attribution requirements.  More detail may be found about these [here](https://wiki.creativecommons.org/wiki/License_Versions#Detailed_attribution_comparison_chart), but as I read them, a mere link pointer will not suffice.

Comment: Unfortunately, what you said " .. The rights given to you ... , of that software. .." can't be understood easly from the license

Comment: @arastirmahesap I disagree, but hopefully what I wrote above clarifies your rights and responsibilities, and answers your question.  Do you know now what you want to know?

Comment: It would be great if you specify what I quoted from your answer is also valid for OSI-approved and FSF free licenses

Comment: @arastirmahesap no doubt.  However, the licence obligations imposed by a licence depend on what it says, which in turn depends on the licence; it isn't possible to give a general-purpose answer covering all licences.  You asked about MIT, and I have answered about that, and CC BY into the bargain.  If there is anything **in your original question** that remains unanswered, please let me know what that is.